# What's the DataContext of the Header elements inside a Hub control?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, localization, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have started to develop for WP 8.1 using Windows Runtime recently, and I have faced a... "problem" that I don't seem to understand.

The application I am currently developing uses a `Hub` control, and I would like to tweak its header's appearance slightly. To do so, I changed the `HeaderTemplate`attribute of the `Hub` control. However, as I tried to localize the textual content of the header (note that this is WinRT, the localization process is slightly different from the process in WP8 and can be found [here](http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/22/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-localizing-apps/)), I "accidentally" fixed the problem by making the template like this:

```
<Hub.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                   Foreground="Red"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Hub.HeaderTemplate>
```

I don't understand why it worked, though. When you do data binding like this (just using the expression `{Binding}`), doesn't the element get the same DataContext as its father? What's happening under the hood? Who's the parent element of the TextBlock, after all?

Thanks in advance.

## EDIT

As igrali asked, here is a more complete view of the XAML:

```
<Page ...
      DataContext="{Binding Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid Background="#FFF6DB">
    <Hub Name="MainPageHub"
         x:Uid="MainPageHub"
         Margin="0,27,0,0">
        <Hub.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                           Foreground="White"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Hub.HeaderTemplate>
...
```

Then, in the /Strings/en-US/Resources.resx, I have a "MainPageHub.Header" property set to "foobar" (just an example), and what I get as a header is actually "foobar" (which is what I wanted, but even so it seems confusing!).

Comment: What are you binding to? Show more XAML. But yes, you are right, it should have the datacontext of the parent element which is probably the Hub Header, and the datacontext should propagate from the top element which has it set. On what element do you set datacontext in xaml?

Comment: @igrali, I have edited the question as you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Tim Heuer explains it here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/04/26/localize-windows-8-application.aspx)

> Notice the x:Uid value here.  This now maps back to the key in your
>   RESW file.  Anything with that starting key will have properties
>   merged into it.  So we can have a key in our RESW for “Text” using the
>   key name MyTextBlock.Text with a value of “Hello World” and the
>   runtime will do the replacement for you.  This applies to properties
>   other than text (i.e. width) as well as attached properties.

All I can add is - notice the x:Uid. It's MainPageHub. In the localized resource file, you have a MainPageHub.Header. This means that the value of the resource string will be set to the Header of the control which has the x:Uid set to MainPageHub.

So, now that it's clear how the Header is set - there's still the binding part. Well, considering you have a different template for the Header, it needs to do the {Binding } part to actually get the value of the header which is set through the resources.

Comment: After giving it some thought, I think I finally got it. Thank you very much :)